# How to keep track of users Graph API authenticating using Facebook in Firebase

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, ionic2, nosql

I'm trying to use Ionic, Firebase and Facebook Graph API for an app. I want people to authenticate with Facebook using Firebase. When a user is authenticated what is the approach for storing information about the user, like age, gender, friends and so on? Also how do I know next time a user login which data belongs to him or her?

Comment: You would typically store user data in a /users node with the users uid being the parent of each child node  /users/uid_0 and the children being age, gender etc. However, this is a super vague question and really no way to answer it directly. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well what I mean is does one store the information retrieved from the Graph API in Firebase or request it from Facebook every time the user authenticates. If one stores it in Firebase, what happens if the user updates it's profile on Facebook, how are those changes reflected, and so on?